# pathPattern with parameters in intent-filter

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want my application to proceed some web links. I've added intent-filter for this in manifest. It looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*.something.com" />
        <data android:pathPattern="/.*/download/.*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It works. But then I was asked to process only those urls, where precise parameter is specified. So, I've changed `pathPattern` like this:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*/download/.*param=.*" />
```

Then I try to open in browser url like `http://something.com/en/download/what?param=1234`
But pattern doesn't work, my application is not offered to open.

I have doubts about parameter. May be `pathPattern` doesn't look at them at all? Or what else I am doing wrong?

Comment: Who would fire the intent that you are interested in?

Comment: User clicks on link in browser, and some Activity from my application should open

Comment: Well, I don't think its possible unless you have a custom browser that would fire intents on opening a link. (You have said it worked ... in what way did it?)

Comment: Android really can send intents from browser urls, that's very cool. For example, try to open Instagram link in browser, and application will be suggested to open.

Answer (score 9):

I know it's late but this might save someone's time.

no parameters or query strings. (thus, **the part after the ? mark is simply not matched against anything**)

Comment: you mean, this is no chances to intercept a parameter string?